# jquery: What happens after binding an event more than once?

Tags: jquery, triggers

Thanks to jQuery, .on method binds a trigger to an element. I have a html like:

```
<div class='xyz'>click me</div>
```

and script like:

```
$('.xyz').on('click', function(){   alert('why?'); });
$('.xyz').on('click', function(){   alert('why?'); });
```

clicking on **click me** div triggers alert 2 times. **It's ok**, But:

1. What exactly happens after binding second click trigger to the div?
2. Is it a browser behavior or its done by jquery variables?

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpmhpm/FCReC/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What exactly happens after binding second click trigger to the div?*

Jquery register's a new click event handler on `.xyz`, No matter, how many event handler's are already attached to your element

*Is it a browser behavior or its done by jquery variables?*

It's done by jquery

---

You can have as many event handler's you want on the same element, consider a scenario -

This is perfectly valid :

```
$('.xyz').on('click', function(){   // do some work });
$('.xyz').on('click', function(){   // do some other work });
```

Comment: So jquery set kind of a variable or array to store binded triggers, am I right?

Comment: Yes, their is a kind of property that every element has `Event Listeners` , You can inspect what event's are attached on particular element on Webkit Developer Tools ,